# seekp() position at the beginnig of new line in file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have a file "first.txt":

```
Chun mee  |Wuyi      |Genmai    |
Pu-erth     |Green      |Flower mix |
Lightly sweet|Strong,smooth|Fresh, strong|
```

Here '|' is delimiter, the first line has 10 symbols in each block (block is the space between delimiters), the second - 11, the third - 13.
I`d like to combinate these lines like this and write it ("rec.txt"):

```
Chun mee  '\t'Pu-erth     '\t'Lightly sweet
Wuyi      '\t'Green      '\t'Strong,smooth 
Genmai    '\t'Flower mix '\t'Fresh, strong
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

fstream& go_line(fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

void func(int iter_num){
    fstream file;
    fstream file_exist;
    string str;
    file_exist.open("first.txt");
    file.open("rec.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios:: trunc | ios::binary);

        if (iter_num < 3){ //iter_num  - num of iterations (lines)
            for(int i = 0; i < iter_num; i++ ){
                 for(int t = 1; t< 4; t++ ){ //t-num of columns          
                      if(i>0 && t==1){
                        file<<endl;
                      }
                      if(i == 0){
                        go_line(file_exist, t); 
                        getline (file_exist, str, '|');
                        file_exist.seekp(0, ios::beg);
                        file<<str<<'\t';
                      }
                     else{
                          switch(t){
                            case 1:
                                //cout<<"case1 "<<endl;
                                file_exist.seekp((i*10)+1, ios::beg);
                                go_line(file_exist, t);
                                getline (file_exist, str, '|');
                                file<<str<<'\t';
                                break;
                            case 2: 
                                //cout<<i<<endl;
                                go_line(file_exist, t);
                                file_exist.seekp((i*11)+1, ios::beg);
                                getline (file_exist, str, '|');
                                file<<str<<'\t';
                            case 3: 
                                //cout<<i<<endl;
                                go_line(file_exist, t);
                                file_exist.seekp((i*13)+1, ios::beg);
                                getline (file_exist, str, '|');
                                file<<str<<'\t';
                          }//switch
                    }//else
                }//for
            }//for
        }//if
}//func

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    func(n);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: 
for example, in case 2 seekp() is not at the beginnig of new line, it`s on the first one. But the idea is - set it at the beginnig of new line and get "Green      " for "Wuyi      ". So, It works incorrect, I have no ideas. 
Thank you for help!

Comment: if you don't mind, can you format your code a bit more properly?

Comment: This code is broken beyond measure. there is no definition of `iter_num`, and there are *mulitple* missing braces. Post code that **compiles**.

Comment: I`ve edited, now it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) from iomanip for formating.

A quick example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream to_format("test/test.txt");            
    ofstream formatted("test/formatted.txt");

    vector<vector<string>> item_matrix;                     // 

    // Populating the matrix.
    for (string line; getline(to_format, line);)
    {
        item_matrix.push_back({});

        stringstream line_(line);                           // string stream used for split the line according to the separator '|'
        for (string item; getline(line_, item, '|');)
        {
            item_matrix.back().push_back(item);             // Add items to the last row.
        }
    }

    // Output the matrix to file.
    // This assume all lines in the original file have the same number of blocks.
    vector<string> new_lines;

    for (int i = 0; i < item_matrix[0].size(); i++)
    {
        new_lines.push_back({});
        for_each(item_matrix.begin(), item_matrix.end(), [&](vector<string> row){
            formatted << setw(25) << left << row[i];
        });
        formatted << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
Chun mee  |Wuyi      |Genmai    |
Pu-erth     |Green      |Flower mix |
Lightly sweet|Strong,smooth|Fresh, strong|
```

Example ouput:

```
Chun mee                 Pu-erth                  Lightly sweet            
Wuyi                     Green                    Strong,smooth            
Genmai                   Flower mix               Fresh, strong
```

Comment: It`s useful, but the problem is to get in output lines like:
Chun mee     Pu-erth    Lightly sweet -- the first line in output file is combination of first lines in the first row in the input file.

Comment: @CropCircle I edited my answer in order to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well the go_line function which u use continue reading until the end of file is reached so that loop has no effect [read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: Yes, but  in go_line function file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n') --> '\n', not EOF.